# enable nyan-mode spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I was reading through:

[Spacemacs Colors Layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/colors)

because I want to get `nyan-mode` working using the hot keys `SPC t m n` as shown on [Github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/colors/local/nyan-mode).

I was able to do this part:

```
To use this configuration layer, add it to your ~/.spacemacs. You  
will need to add **colors** to the existing dotspacemacs-configuration-
layers list in this file.
```

However I do not understand how to enable it.

where does

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
  (colors :variables colors-enable-nyan-cat-progress-bar t)))
```

go? I see nothing in my .spacemacs for it or am I missing how to do this completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please (re)-read the [FAQ](http://spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html) and [DOCUMENTATION](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html).

But to add custom layers look for the following lines in your `.spacemacs` configuration file:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers()
  ...
    (setq-default
    ...
        dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
        '(
         ...
         ;; git
         ;; company
         ;; PLACE NEW CONFIGURATION LAYER HERE
         (colors: variables colors-enable-nyan-cat-progress-bar t)
     ...
```

*Note that there could be text in between hence the ellipses "..."*

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is pretty confusing in regards to packages. Probably because there is so much you can do with them.